# can anyone see anything wrong with this js / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the following script to ask the user to confirm clicking a button depending on a system setting.

The system setting is stored in a hidden field set from code behind.

Markup:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfConfirmOnApproval" runat="server" Value="False" />
```

cs:

```
//Read the confirm on approval setting
hfConfirmOnApproval.Value = Objects.Engine.Settings.Instance.ConfirmOnApproval.ToString();
```

js:

```
//Get whether to confirm on approval
var _confirmOnApproval = new Boolean($('#hfConfirmOnApproval').val());

if ( _confirmOnApproval ? confirm('Are you sure you want to approve this item?') : true ) 
{

    // do work

}
```

The problem is that the confirm message box is being displayed even though _confirmOnApproval is set to false?

I only want the message box to appear if its set to true.

The _ConfirmOnApproval is false at the moment

SOLUTION:

js:

```
var _confirmOnApproval = $('#<%=hfConfirmOnApproval.ClientID %>').val() == "True" ? true : false;

if ( _confirmOnApproval  ? confirm('Are you sure you want to approve this item?') : true ) {
//Do work
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you've used `new Boolean` to create a Boolean object, and `typeof _confirmOnApproval` will return "Object":

```
var x = new Boolean(false); //Boolean object
if(x) {
   console.log("hello"); //This will always execute
}
var y = false; //Literal boolean primitive
if(y) {
   console.log("hello"); //This won't
}
```

You could get rid of `new Boolean` and just compare the value:

```
if(_confirmOnApproval == "False")
```

Comment: ah, ok so its because of the new Boolean("") constructor, in that case how should I instantiate it? would this work...  var _confirmOnApproval = $('#hfConfirmOnApproval').val() == "True" ? true : false;

Comment: Or even just var _confirmOnApproval = ($('#hfConfirmOnApproval').val() == "True");

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to James's answer you'd have to change your existing code to explicitly check the boolean condition like

```
var _confirmOnApproval = new Boolean($('#hfConfirmOnApproval').val());
if ( _confirmOnApproval === true ? confirm('Are you sure you want to approve this item?') : true ) 
{
    // do work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that it will always have a value... try taking the length of that value, that will probably work.

Comment: Do you mean if (_confirmOnApproval.Length = 4 ? confirm('...') : true)   its a bool so it should work!?

Answer (score 0):

the `asp:HiddenField ID` attribute is not always exactly the same as the `input id` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var _confirmOnApproval = $('input[type=hidden][id$=hfConfirmOnApproval]').val();

if ( _confirmOnApproval === "False" ? confirm('Are you sure you want to approve this item?') : true ) 
{

    // do work

}
```